# Common way to access custom HTTP header in View class in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a custom header like UserId in my request and have created a view class extending APIView in Django rest framework as follows:

```
class Process(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        userId = request.META['HTTP_USERID']
        # do something
    def post(self, request):
        userId = request.META['HTTP_USERID']
        # do something
```

Is there a way to access the header userId without accessing it twice in each of the functions et and post?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make UserId a **member** of Class

```
class Process(APIView)::
    def get(self,lists):
        userId = request.META['HTTP_USERID']
        self.userId=userId

    def post(self,request):
        userId=self.userId
```

Comment: This solution won't work. If I only execute "post" function, then Process class won't have any attribute userId as you have assigned it in the "get" function.